# AirPort Extreme is disconnected from the internet when in bridge mode

Tags: network, wifi, internet, airport

I have to use the router provided by my ISP to connect to the internet, but I also want to use my AirPort Extreme.

DHCP is set to on in the ISP's router. When I connect the router to the AirPort, and set the AirPort to `DHCP and NAT`, it seems to work fine, but it also says `Double NAT`.

So I found out that I needed to turn off one of the DHCP servers, and decided to put the AirPort Extreme to `Bridge` mode. But when I do that, I get no internet connection. In the AirPort Utility, the Internet light is yellow and it says `connection disconnected`. It also shows the DNS servers as `192.168.1.1` which I guess is the router's IP address.

Why does this happen? What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Could you please share a little more information on your settings? What IP address does the modem assign to your device when connected directly? How do you connect your modem to your AirPort Extreme? Is Wi-Fi enabled on it, and if so, what are the settings? DNS server coinciding with the modem IP should work fine, provided it has its own DNS servers properly configured. Thanks!

Comment: A few more details is required for this question to be properly assessed. 1. What ISP modem/router/gateway are you using? 2. Which Airport Extreme version are you running(the new tall ones or the square ones from previous generation) I've had this type of issue before which resulted in adjusting the ISP provided modem/router/gateway. Let us know the above to properly proceed.

Comment: I just started my computer, and for some reason it is working now. Last night I did set the DNS manually, it might have been the reason. Or this thing is happening every now and then. I'll check and if it happens again, I will add those details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real solution, but it might help if you have the same issue.

I still get the problem, and every time I get it, **I restart the AirPort Extreme** (by unplugging it from the outlet, waiting a bit, and plugging it back), and it works (until it stops working again). This happens around once a month or every other month, so it is not a big deal for me now.